# Android Hello World is not running

Tags: android

I also got this same problem from last day. i tried 2-3 time to uninstall/install `android sdk` from my computer. I install new `eclipse`, `new workspace`, `eclipse update`. every this i did from last day. but i could not run a *HELLO WORLD Project*.

Where ever i run my project;

Run as > Android Project, A dialog is populated

`("YOUR PROJECT CONTAINS SOME ERROR(S), PLEASE FIX THEM BEFORE RUNNING YOUR APPLICATION").`

i am working on android from last 1 year. but i never faced this type of problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476145/android-project-not-running

Comment: you have a tab in eclipse called "logcat". Post what is displayed there so that we can see the error and help

Comment: got your error tab in eclipse and fix them, its saying your project is having some compile time errors, or else post your code for fast response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails, try deleting ~/.android/debug.keystore.  Sometimes your debug key expires, and you need to sync up with the SDK.